# Ubuntu stopped to show Wi-Fi network names and operations on them

Tags: wireless

Current display is following

[image]

As you see, no Wi-Fi networks shows. Although I am using one to type this message.

Consequently I can't disconnect from Wi-Fi delibrately and reconnect to it.

How to fix?

Comment: Does reboot fix it? Or `systemctl restart network-manager.service` ?

Comment: Yes, `systemctl` solved the problem. Reboot solving the problem temporary, but then I am falling into problem again.

Comment: Does it happen after a few minutes whithout apparent reason? Or is it always after coming back from suspension, for example?

Comment: @M.Becerra most often it comes from suspension